# get the class that triggered an event - Java

Tags: java, events, swing, triggers

Is there a way in Swing in an `ActionEvent` handler to get a reference to the object, that triggered the event?

Comment: your title talks about the class -i was assuming classname-, but your question says object (so the instance of the class). Which of the two do you need? The classname could be send in the intent, but the object is -AFAIK- not so easy

Comment: what interface are you implementing ? ActionListener..?

Comment: @Nanne - sry for ambiguity, it's object. @h3xStream - the default java.awt.event.ActionEvent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about Swing events.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     if (evt.getSource() == ...)
}
```